# How to apply a user defined function (UDF) to a document field in mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

Lets say you have the following schema

```
employee( firstname, lastname, dept)
```

Say we want the `lastname` to be uppercase for all the rows in the table (the uppercase function might be a built-in function in the DBMS, but lets assume it's a UDF)

In SQL we would have done the following

```
Select firstname, toUpper(lastname) as lastname, dept
From employees
```

What is the equivalent in mangoDB ? Knowing that we have a document `employees` which contains the following JSONs:

```
...
{ "firstname": "jhon", "lastname": "doe", "dept": "marketing"}
...
{ "firstname": "jean", "lastname": "dupont", "dept": "sales"}
...
```

The goal is to directly obtain the changed data using mongoDB query API, without writing extra JS code to get the job done.

I Know how to save/import a UDF in [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/). What I don't know is how to apply it to a result:

```
db.employees.find().apply_my_udf(....)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [`$toUpper`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/) in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "firstname": 1,
    "lastname": { "$toUpper": "$firstname" },
    "dept": 1,
  }}
])
```

The aggregation framework is basically where you go for "tranformations" on data of any kind. The `.find()` method is really just for "plain selection" of documents and supports simple "inclusion" or "exclusion" of properties only.

If you have some familiarity with SQL, then [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the core documentation is a good place to start with understanding how to apply common phrases.

Of course as an "alternative" approach you can also apply the "transform" to the data "after" the results are fetched from the server. All drivers provide some form of [`cursor.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) for this very purpose.

As a JavaScript shell example:

```
db.employees.find().map( d => Object.assign(d, { lastname: d.lastname.toUpperCase() }) )
```

Which essentially does the same thing, but the transformation is done as each document is retrieved from the server as opposed to transforming on the server itself.

Comment: the `toUpper` was just an example. Lets say, I have a UDF named `my_udf`. Can I do something like this:
`db.employees.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "firstname": 1,
    "lastname": { "$my_udf": "$firstname" },
    "dept": 1,
  }}
])`

Comment: @MassyB I was actually still writing. Point is you either use the supported [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), or you apply such things "after" the results are returned. But you cannot execute JavaScript functions "within" an aggregation pipeline. That's not how it works

Comment: Thank you very much !
I was looking for a solution on the server side ...

Comment: @MassyB Well there are plenty of operators and you can do quite a few things. You should note that it generally really only makes sense to apply any kind of transformation on the server itself when that results in a "significant" reduction of data, or is a general requirement of further aggregation operations. If that is not the case then processing the transform on the cursor is what you "should" really be doing. Just because XYZ database allowed you to do something, does not mean it's a good idea. So something to consider.